# How to write a regular expression for extracting 2-3 letter Australian state abbreviation?

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract the state data (`NSW`, `SA`) from the following strings:

1. `55 Christie St, St Leonards NSW, Australia`
2. `338-340 Tapleys Hill Rd, Seaton SA, Australia`
3. `Kincumber South NSW, Australia`

For this purpose I wrote the regular expression `.*(\w[A-Z]{2,3}?),.*`, which I invoke using the code shown below.

```
private final Pattern statePattern;

statePattern = Pattern.compile(aStatePattern, Pattern.DOTALL);

private String extractText(final String aAddress, final Pattern aPattern) {
    final Matcher matcher = aPattern.matcher(aAddress);

    if (matcher.matches())
    {
        return matcher.group(1).trim();
    }
    return "";
}
```

This regular expression works fine with 2 of the three strings, but fails to extract `SA` from `338-340 Tapleys Hill Rd, Seaton SA, Australia`.

How should I change the regex and/or the code so that it extracts `SA` from `338-340 Tapleys Hill Rd, Seaton SA, Australia` and `NSW` from two other strings?

Comment: This seems *really* fragile, esp. if this data is in any way user-generated. A lot of people type in ALL CAPS for instance, so "123 ANY ST, NSW, AUSTRALIA" would give you "ST".

Comment: Try `([A-Z]{2,3}),\sAustralia` and change `matcher.matches()` to `matcher.find()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow `.*` with a non-greedy quantifier `?` and remove the `\w` before your character class. Also remove the `?` quantifier following your range `{2,3}`, it is not neccessary at all.

```
.*?([A-Z]{2,3}),.*
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/xC7tK9)

I would recommend using the beginning of string `^` anchor and perhaps use a word boundary `\b` as well.

```
^.*?(\b[A-Z]{2,3}),.*
```

Answer (score 1):

A positive lookahead should suit your needs:

```
[A-Z]+(?=, Australia$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/tOc4DZOPpwy2YyGL)

---

Note that this could be improved by allowing spaces for example.

Comment: The best way, because this won't make false positive when uppercase letters happen to be somehwere else.

Even better: use a list of state code: "(NSW|SA|NT|WA|Qld|ACT|Tas|Vic)(?=, Australia$)"

Answer (score 0):

The below regex will extract the Capital letter alphabets present just before the string `, Australia`

```
\s([A-Z]+),\s\w+$
```

BY providing the $ symbol at the last, it would match from the last. We don't need to match from the begining.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aG3tH0)

Comment: "try this"-style answers are not useful. Say *what* you changed, and *why*.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply look for the capitalized character class followed by a comma, as such:

```
String[] inputs = { "55 Christie St, St Leonards NSW, Australia",
                "338-340 Tapleys Hill Rd, Seaton SA, Australia", "Kincumber South NSW, Australia" };
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{2,3}(?=,)");
Matcher m;
for (String input: inputs) {
    m = p.matcher(input);
    // use a while loop if you happen to expect more than one match per input String
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf("Found: \"%s\"%n", m.group());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: "NSW"
Found: "SA"
Found: "NSW"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^.*(\b[A-Z]{2,3}),[^,]+$
```

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/uC1bT7)**

`^` begin with
`.*` matches any character zero or more times
`\b[A-Z]{2,3}` match an upper case word of 2 to 3 characters (you can change the limits if you want)
`,` matches the character , literally
`[^,]+` match one or more character not containing a comma